# How to paginate django-filter filtered queries with Django?

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-filter

I have been using the django-filter app to filter models. When I try to use Django's paginator, to paginate from the filtered query, it does not work. All results are put on to one page, although the page numbers are on the bottom. When I click on a different page number, the results are unfiltered at put on to one page.

Does any body know a solution to this?

### views.py

```
from .models import Video
from django.shortcuts import render
from .filters import VideoFilter
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger


def search(request):
    video_list = Video.objects.all()
    video_filter = VideoFilter(request.POST, queryset=video_list)
    paginator = Paginator(video_filter.qs, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        videos = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        videos = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        videos = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'search/user_list.html', {'filter': video_filter,'videos':videos})
```

### search/user_list.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
  <ul>
  {% for video in filter.qs %}
    <li>{{ video.title }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  {% if videos.has_other_pages %}
    <ul class="pagination">
      {% if videos.has_previous %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ videos.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
      {% endif %}
      {% for i in videos.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if videos.number == i %}
          <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
        {% else %}
          <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% if videos.has_next %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ videos.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the paginator's `object_list` instead of the filterset's `.qs` property.

```
{% for video in videos.object_list %}
    <li>{{ video.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried that, but when I click on a different page, the results are unfiltered.

Comment: The FilterSet isn't persistent across requests, so you need to copy the relevant query parameters in the "next" and "previous" links. You will most likely need to generate a suitable `next_url` & `prev_url` in your view's `get_context_data()` method.